# Android app getting crashed : com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout : Error

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I have started to learn Android. I am trying to work on Google Map APIs. My app is crashing every time I am trying to launch it, upon investigation I found one notification in `build.gradle` file.

[Please refer this image to see the message from compiler](https://ibb.co/farD2k)

I changed `com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha7` to `com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha9` to support `compileSdkVersion 26`. I am not finding any relevant links on Google to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your compile sdk version is greater than your support libraries,

try modifying your gradle as

```
android {
...
compileSdkVersion 25
...
}
```

and within the dependency you can add

`compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'`

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42374426/3511011), if you run the Gradle command you can see what of your dependencies has a different buildtools version.

From the post:

> Run a Gradle dependency report to see what your full tree of
>   dependencies is. From there, you will see which one of your libraries
>   is asking for a different version of the Android Support libraries.
>   For whatever it is asking for, you can ask for it directly with the
>   25.2.0 version, or use Gradle's other conflict resolution approaches to arrange to get the same version.
>
> Run:
>
> ```
> ./gradlew -q dependencies <module-name>:dependencies --configuration compile
> ```
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> ./gradlew -q dependencies app:dependencies --configuration compile
> ```